# Access SQL multiple join with multiple tables

Tags: sql, select, join

I would like to join three tables, T1, T2 and T3, with reference columns f1, f2 and f3, according to the following criteria:

Show all records from T1, only show records from T2 where T1.f1 = T2.f1 and T1.f2 = T2.f2, and show records from T3 where T2.f3 = T3.f3.

f1 values (ID) only show up once on T1, with only one associated f2 and many times in T2, but only once with each f2 (Date Stamp) in T2, so by matching both (ID and date) i wanted to match unique records from T3 to f1 values in T1.

I need to match records in T3 for each f1 in table 1, with T2 serving as a connection between those.

I tried

```
SELECT T1.*, T2.f1, T2.f2, T2.f3, T3.*
FROM ((T1 LEFT JOIN T2 ON T1.f1 = T2.f1 AND T1.f2 = T2.f2) LEFT JOIN T3 ON T2.f3=T3.f3)
```

However, not only all my T1 f1 records are showing, but i get many duplicate lines, probably because of the many f1 repeated values in T2.

I'm not very used to SQL statements, so please help me see what is wrong.

Comment: Is F2 (Date Stamp) a date or datetime column? If the column is capturing times to a millisecond precision, there may be a difference which would call for SQL to not allow them to JOIN together. Are they identical?

Comment: I'm sorry, how do I know if it is T-SQL? I created a query on Access 2013 and tried to edit the SQL View.
Date comes from Excel Short Date type of fields, and it is the same (mm/dd/yyyy) in both fields, how do I find out if it is a datetime?